# Molasses flood, "50 feet a second"

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Reading an article about the famous 'molasses flood' in Boston ([Scientists finally decode the Great Molasses Flood of 1919](https://www.csmonitor.com/Science/2016/1129/Scientists-finally-decode-the-Great-Molasses-Flood-of-1919)) and read the following:

> The flood began shortly after 12:40 pm local time on Jan. 15, 1919,
>   when a giant storage tank – 50 feet tall and 90 feet wide – collapsed
>   on Boston's waterfront at the Purity Distilling Co., releasing more
>   than 2.3 million gallons of molasses into Boston's North End. **The wave
>   moved through the neighborhood at more than 50 feet per second.**

**Question:** Is that rate of fluid movement realistic and possible?

Comment: Might [skeptics.se] be more appropriate for this type of claim-checking question?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the Scientific American article [The Science of the Great Molasses Flood](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/molasses-flood-physics-science/) of 1 August 2013 :

> A wave of molasses does not behave like a wave of water. Molasses is a non-Newtonian fluid, which means that its viscosity depends on the forces applied to it, as measured by shear rate. Consider non-Newtonian fluids such as toothpaste, ketchup and whipped cream. In a stationary bottle, these fluids are thick and goopy and do not shift much if you tilt the container this way and that. When you squeeze or smack the bottle, however, applying stress and increasing the shear rate, the fluids suddenly flow. Because of this physical property, a wave of molasses is even more devastating than a typical tsunami. In 1919 the dense wall of syrup surging from its collapsed tank initially moved fast enough to sweep people up and demolish buildings, only to settle into a more gelatinous state that kept people trapped.